# Executing Perl command from shell script not resulting into anything

Tags: unix, shell, shell-script, perl

I am trying to execute the below command from a shell script:
`perl -pi -e 's/Ç/|/g' diff_new_old.dat`
This command gets executed without any errors, but the execution doesn't do the intended substitution. It doesn't seem like shell has an issue with execution of perl command, since         `perl -pi -e 's/\n/\r\n/g' diff_new_old.dat` works fine. It looks like an issue with special character substitution.

When I execute the same command directly on $ prompt, it executes fine and substitutes all Ç characters with | in the file. I want to automate this process and thus need a way to get this done from a shell script.

I have also tried using the sed 's/Ç/|/' command. But this results into below error:
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unterminated `s' command

Please let me know what I can do to achieve the substitution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to tell perl that the script contains UTF-8 characters:

```
perl -Mutf8 -pi -e 's/Ç/|/g' diff_new_old.dat
```

see http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html